# Form value is null in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

JS newbie here. I have searched all over stackoverflow before posting this question, please comment on the question if it is a duplicate and need to be removed.

I'm creating a form in google chrome extension which takes an input and logs it in the console when the submit button is pressed.

I'm able to fetch the element(by Id), but there is no value in it even after I'm clicking the submit button after entering the zip code. Here is the code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var zipCode = document.getElementById("zipCode");

    console.log("Zip Code is: " + zipCode.id);
    console.log("Zip Code value: " + zipCode.value);
}, false);


<body style="width:320px;height:580px;">
    <form action="/main.html" style="position: center; text-align: left; padding-left: 20px">
        <h3>Zip Code</h3>
        <input type="text" id="zipCode" align="left" size="8" style="padding-left: 0%; padding-bottom: 10px;font-family: 'Open Sans'">
        <input type="submit" id="button" value="  Tap" style="font-family: 'Open Sans'" name="Submitted zip code">
    </form>
</body>
```

The console output is:

```
Zip Code is: zipCode
Zip Code value:
```

Answer (score 2):

guess you want this,you can get the `value` only after the `button` have been clicked;

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var zipCode = document.getElementById("zipCode");

  console.log("Zip Code is: " + zipCode.id);
  var btn = document.getElementById('button');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Zip Code value: " + zipCode.value);
  }, false)

}, false);
```

```html
<body style="width:320px;height:580px;">
  <form action="/main.html" style="position: center; text-align: left; padding-left: 20px">
    <h3>Zip Code</h3>
    <input type="text" id="zipCode" align="left" size="8" style="padding-left: 0%; padding-bottom: 10px;font-family: 'Open Sans'">
    <input type="submit" id="button" value="click me" style="font-family: 'Open Sans'" name="Submitted zip code">
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @xianshenglu. What does the method event.preventDefault() do?

Comment: prevent the form submited @kai,if the form was submited you can't see the console

Answer (score 1):

When the submit button is pressed the page is reloaded so there is no value in

```
<input type="text" id="zipCode" align="left" size="8" style="padding-left: 0%; padding-bottom: 10px;font-family: 'Open Sans'">
```

at the time you try to get it ("DOMContentLoaded"). If you want to get the value after the submit button is pressed you need to get it from the url where it is being stored as values after the `?`

First your form field needs a `name` attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="zipCode" name="zipCode" align="left" size="8" style="padding-left: 0%; padding-bottom: 10px;font-family: 'Open Sans'">
```

and then you can get the passed values using the URL object:

```
var url = new URL(location.href);
var zipCode = url.searchParams.get("zipCode");
```

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian, Sorry I have not updated the question properly, but we are discussing form submission in chrome-extension. Do your suggestion work for chrome-extensions as well? I've seen on many documentations that `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()` is the most preferred way to load the form details.

Comment: You are correct that the form itself is fully functioning after `DOMContentLoaded` but the values aren't in it at this moment